# Как сохранить данные в форме

Tags: php

Всем привет, прочитал статью, и не очень понял, у меня похожий вопрос, может на моем примере объясните, мне надо что бы число вбитое в поле `fot` сохранился после нажатия на кнопку, для того что бы человек если отвлекся он увидел какое число он туда вбивал только что

```
<strong>Укажите сечение кабеля:</strong>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="number" name="fot">
      <input type="submit" value="Convert">
      <input type="hidden" name="scroll" value="">
    </form>
    <script>
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    $('input[name="scroll"]').val($(window).scrollTop());
});
<?php if (!empty($_REQUEST['scroll'])): ?>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, <?php echo intval($_REQUEST['scroll']); ?>);
});
<?php endif; ?>
</script>
    <br>
    <strong>~ Размер диаметра пружины:</strong>
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      echo sqrt($_POST['fot'] * 4 / 3.14);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить атрибут `value` в инпут

```
<input type="number" name="fot" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fot']) ? $_POST['fot'] : ''; ?>">
```